# Pass values and parameters from HTML to CGI

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am using post method in html to pass the parameters and values to cgi file. From that cgi file I'm extracting the values and parameters. I have tried the code below,

**HTML:**

```
    <form action="http://hostname.com/manipulation.cgi?name5=value5&name6=value6&name7=value7&name8=value8" method="POST"> </form>
```

**CGI:** ***manipulation.cgi***

```
use strict;
use CGI;
my $query ->new CGI;
print $query->header();

my @paramNames = $query->param; #Receive N number of parameters
my @paramValues = map $query->param($_), $query->param; #Receive N number of parameters values
print $query->h4("@paramNames,@paramValues");
```

But I'm not able to get the expected output.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see an issue with the code (although it would be better to print a valid HTML document). What is the error you're getting? What are you trying to fix it? Why are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not getting the parameters and values.
output expected: 
name5 name6 name7 name8, value5 value6 value7 value8

Comment: Have you look at the apache error log?

Comment: I have changed from $query->param to $query->url_param. Now it is working fine.

Comment: `my $query ->new CGI` - this doesn't look right. I hope you mean `my $query = CGI->new`. If you don't cut and paste your exact code then it's harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url_param` — get a parameter from the `URL`.

```
use strict;
use CGI;
my $query ->new CGI;
print $query->header();

my @paramNames = $query->url_param; #Receive N number of parameters
my @paramValues = map $query->url_param($_), $query->url_param; #Receive N number of parameters values
print $query->h4("@paramNames,@paramValues");
```

Comment: This is a code-only answer. You should explain in a few words how your answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing makes no sense. If all of your parameters are in the URL, then why are you using POST, not GET? In fact, why are you using a form at all?

If you are using GET then `param` will give you the parameters from the URL.

If you are using POST then `param` will give you the parameters from the HTTP request body and `url_param` will give you the parameters from the URL.

So it seems that you need to switch to using `url_param`.

It's worth pointing out that learning CGI in 2014 is a bit like learning to use a typewriter. It will work, and some of the skills will be useful. But you'd be far better advised to learn [something a little more up to date](http://plackperl.org/).